# Messed up with constraint layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm new to android programming with android studio and much confused with the ConstraintLayout feature which is by default provided by android studio. I made a layout by drag and drop as [LayoutBeforeConstraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzaSU.png)

Then, by rule, I click 'Infer constraints' and this happens : [LayoutAfterConstraints][2]

As I inferred, the elements are cluttered as evident, and I can't find the switch which seems to reduce to a point!

And if I move an element, e.g the text view then surrounding elements also displace.

If no constraints are applied, everything will shift to top-left as known, and I don't know how to revert to any other layout.

Can anyone explain me what happens behind all these?

(For information, this app is focused to suggest a list of tourist destinations based on what users have selected. The seekbar is for selecting a temperature, switch is for population preference. Checkboxes are as visible. If you want, please suggest me some ideas for enhancing app.)
xml file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6pjPs8ppPUWblBkQ0NKSTlMUmc/view?usp=sharing

(Sorry I could'nt post more than 2 links)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do it like as shown in picture

Comment: Did, but same happened.

Comment: share your layout screenshot and xml file

Comment: Screenshots of the layout were specified in the question... as my reputation is below 10 so images won't show in the question. Please click on the links for screenshots... sharing xml file

Comment: http://localhost:63342/-d1mtshnvrqgul37rufg9te5e72gadr0cqa1d6/SuggestMeATripPlease/layout/activity_main.xml

Comment: your xml file post here

Comment: username and password required

Comment: post your xml file in your question